# Prestashop 1.7.7 E-Mail Input Validation for Domain Name

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

i looking for a solution in Prestashop for correct E-Mail Input field format validation.

A normal email xyz@domain.com will check for the @ symbol but not for domain dot(!) com.

So i can write into the checkout email field as guest: xyz@domain but the dot and com missing.

Somebody have some idea for that?

Thanks

Akos

Answer (score 0):

The email validity check is handled in /classes/Validate.php
into the

```
public static function isEmail($email)
{
}
```

method.

You can consider editing or overriding it to suit your needs.